# Big numbers in Redis Sorted Set

Tags: redis, biginteger, sortedset

I would like to store values as a score in a redis sorted set that be be as big as 10^24 (and if possible even 2^256)

What are the integer size limits with ZRANGE?

For some context I'm trying to implement a ranking of top holders for a custom ethereum token. e.g. https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances

I want to hold the balances in a Redis DB and access it through `node.js`. I can retrieve the actual balances using `web3`, in case the db crashes or something. The point is i would like to have the data sorted and i would like to be able to access the data blazingly fast.

Answer (score 2):

Quotation from the Redis documentation about sorted sets:

[Range of integer scores that can be expressed precisely](https://redis.io/commands/zadd#range-of-integer-scores-that-can-be-expressed-precisely)

> **Redis sorted sets use a double 64-bit floating point number to represent the score**. In all the architectures we support, this is represented as an IEEE 754 floating point number, that is able to **represent precisely integer numbers between -(2^53) and +(2^53)** included. In more practical terms, all the integers between -9007199254740992 and 9007199254740992 are perfectly representable. **Larger integers, or fractions, are internally represented in exponential form, so it is possible that you get only an approximation of the decimal number**, or of the very big integer, that you set as score.

So when leaving the precise range and an approximation of the score is good enough for your use case, [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding) that 2^1023 would be the highest exponent possible.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of the aprroximation that goes on for bigger numbers. I should've specified it in the question. Is there a way to keep the values exact?

Comment: No, you are limited to the precision of floating points which gets inaccurate for high numbers and there is no workaround specified.